# Importing Own Python Module in Mac

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, import, module

I have created own **Python Modules**.

Directory Structure:

```
main_dir
    |--- __init__.py
    |--- test
           |--- __init__.py
           |--- test1.py
    |--- lib
           |--- __init__.py
           |--- lib1.py
```

I imported **lib1.py** inside **test1.py** using this

```
from lib.lib1 import Lib
```

and running the **test1.py** using this

```
python -m test/test1
```

This works in **Ubuntu** and I am able to run my python (**test1.py**) script **successfully** while having **problem** in **MAC OS X**. It throws

```
/usr/bin/python: No module named test/test1
```

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When any module is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named spam.py in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`. [Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

You can either set `main_dir` to the `sys.path` or add the path programmatically before importing your module.

```python
import os
import sys

yourpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) #current filepath

parentpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(yourpath, os.pardir))
sys.path.append(parentpath)

from lib.lib1 import Lib
```

Comment: I used add the path programmatically with no success. Inside **yourpath< Add path_upto_main_dir>**. Is it correct ?

Comment: @iNikkz - `yourpath = <path-upto-test-folder>`. `yourpath` is initialized with the path to the directory of the current file (ie `test1.py`)

Comment: @iNikkz - If you are going to hard code the path (which I'm not recommending to do), simply set the variable `parentpath` to the path of `main_dir`.

Comment: Again same issue. Inside yourpath = <path-to-test> and run the test1.py using both commands **python -m test/test1** / ** python test/test1.py** and also by going inside test folder and run **python test1.py**. No success

Comment: @iNikkz - What are the contents of your `lib1.py` file? Does have a class named `Lib`? And it should be `python -m lib.lib1.Lib` It should be the module name not the path. That command will only work if you edit the `sys.path` permanently.